# Ruby thread pool based on Ops/sec rate limiting

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I've looked around the available thread pools for ruby such as [`connection_pool`](https://github.com/mperham/connection_pool) which works like:

```
pool = ConnectionPool.new(size: 5, timeout: 20) do 
  @user
end

results = ['foo', 'bar', 'a', 'z'].map do |thing|
  Thread.new do
    pool.with do |user|
      user.fetch(thing)
    end
  end
end.map(&:join).map(&:value)
```

This would effectively only run 5 concurrent fetch operations at any given time.

However my use case involves an API that imposes a rate limit of 5 calls per second, so the regular concurrent limit with no time window correlation wouldn't help me.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You use connection pools to speed up operations. If you need to deliberately slow things down then you need a sequential queue with a built-in rate-limiter or retry mechanism with a back-off interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common workaround is to sleep the appropriate amount:

```
 # Schedule threads
 threads = something.map { |foo| Thread.new... }
 # Record time now
 start_time = Time.now
 # Wait for threads to finish
 threads.each(&:join)
 # Record elapsed time
 elapsed_time = Time.now - start_time
 # Calculate necessary wait time
 sleep_time = thread_count * REQUEST_DELAY - elapsed_time
 # Sleep if necessary
 sleep sleep_time if sleep_time > 0
```

I omitted the details, but I guess you get the general idea.